# Typedefinition interchange in two header files

Tags: c

I have two header files that should use typedefs of each other. Here is the situation:

For example:

In header file **server.h**

```
typedef struct
{
   int myint;
}ServerSelfData;

typedef struct
{
   ServerSelfData servData;
   ClientSelfData clData;
}SERVER_Data;
```

Into the second header file called **client.h** we have:

```
typedef struct
{
   int myint;
}ClientSelfData;

typedef struct
{
   ClientSelfData clData;
   ServerSelfData servData;
}CLIENT_Data;
```

So during the compilation there will be error in one of these definitions. In which one depends on which file is included first.

Is there any workaround/solution of this problem?

Comment: I'd start to think to have 3 headers. The third is the one that include `client.h` and `server.h`  and where `SERVER_Data` and `CLIENT_Data` are defined.

Comment: That would solve the problem. Ok, but what if the two structure type-definitions include each other? Then we can not separate them into three files. The example above was metha-code to explain the situation. It is rather principal representation of my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before these header files, you can declare the structs. Later complete the struct with a name.

```
typedef struct ServerSelfData ServerSelfData;
typedef struct CLIENT_Data CLIENT_Data;

typedef struct ServerSelfData
{
   int myint;
}ServerSelfData;
```

Comment: Now I get the error: `error: field 'servData' has incomplete type`

Comment: I suggest that It now knows about the type, but doesn't know how much space to separate for that type.

Comment: @Hairi You should either complete the type declaration (give all their members) before their first use (Structure member in your case) or restrict yourself to use pointer to those types.

Comment: I believe this is the case. OK, that answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Hairi I am glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of `ServerSelfData` and `ClientSelfData` could me moved to separate header files (or one separate header file) which would be included in both `server.h` and `client.h`.